# Programming in Oracle Apex, is it hard?

Tags: oracle, security, web-applications, oracle-apex

So I am starting an internship this week, I will be working on making some changes to an existing Oracle Apex web app which they use for tracking and metrics. In particular, they don't have very granular authorization set up, meaning that either you have full control or you don't. They want me to come up with something to set up access for non-tech users like the business, for example, and limit their rights to the system.

How hard is apex to work with? I looked into it a bit, it does seem fairly straightforward, but is there more to it that I am not aware of? Also, I am a little surprised that there is no built in functionality to let you set up complex permissions?

Comment: What's your definition of hard? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohs_scale_of_mineral_hardness?

Comment: I mean...how challenging do you think it would be to learn it from scratch? I have done prior .NET development and some PERL/VB scripting plus some web experience. Oracle Apex is brand new for me.

Comment: There is simply no way to objectively measure the difficulty of programming in language X. It will vary wildly from person to person, over time. Even if it didn't, how to do quantify "difficulty?"

Comment: Alright, well that is a rather philosophical answer, which is not really a valid answer on Stackoverflow. By the way, Matt, there is such a thing as overall opinion about a language. For example, the vast majority of people I know think that C is a nuisance and hard to learn (even though it is powerful). Also, the majority can agree that VB is very easy to use and learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been working in Apex since August now, and did 4 years of Oracle Forms before this, so PL/SQL wasn't an issue for me. HTML and Javascript i also knew, just not as in-depth, but i believe i've picked up nicely so far.

What i'm doing at the moment is migrating a bunch of old Oracle Forms to Apex. So far my experience is that it can be very easy and fast to pump out the basics, but making your pages more dynamical or user-friendly can eat away some time. Still, the framework is very solid, save for some niggles. For example, they have a javascript api, which handles a lot like jquery. I can mostly get done what i want to, and i think the most time i've "wasted" so far, has been getting javascript code to work the way i want it.

Recently i've also been implementing some authorisation, and i must say it isn't really that hard! You can provide some authorisation schemes, and simply apply those to pages, regions or items. I of course don't know what you really mean with 'complex' permissions ;) There is always the possibility of using the APIs and do manual calls to verify authorisation.

If you're really totally new, then simply head over to [apex.oracle.com](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/apex/documentation/index.html), and take the 2-day developer guide to get a quick feel for the environment. You'll have to request a workspace, can do the exercises, and play around a bit.

Answer (score 1):

We were looking at apex a year ago. And canceled. It's easy to make standard things, but it's not convenient to develop something specific. May be, we were looking not very properly, indeed.